# Inverse of $1-g-g^{-1}$ in group ring $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ for $o(g)=5$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm trying to prove that if $G$ is a group and $g\in G$ is an element of order $5$ then $x=1-g-g^{-1}$ is an unit element in the group ring $\mathbb{Z}[G]$. I'm trying to find an explicit inverse  by computing $xg^r$ for $r=1,2,3,4$ and trying to add them in a good way to get $1$. But so far I can't find a good "combination". Any hints on how to compute an inverse for this element?.

[EDIT]

I found a solution for this but it is probably the hardest way. I'm trying to find an inverse of the form $a+bg+cg^2+dg^3+eg^4$, so i take the equation $x(a+bg+cg^2+dg^3+eg^4)=1$ and it becomes a linear algebra problem. I found by solving the $5\times 5$ integer linear system that $a=1,b=-1,c=0,d=-1,e=0$ is a solution, i.e., $x(1-g-g^4)=1$. 
I think there should be other ways to approach these kind of exercises.

Comment: The solution is $a=1$, $c=d=-1$, $b=e=0$. (not what you currently have.)

Comment: This $\ (1-g-g^5) = (1-g+g^2)(1-g^2-g^3)\ $ may help you, but your linear algebra approach is correct.

Comment: I thought I was getting somewhere with the automorphism $\phi$ of $\mathbb Z[G]$ induced by $g\mapsto g^2$, and the observation that $u\phi(u)$ is a fixed point, but I couldn't quite get all the way there. Maybe I'm overlooking some obvious simplification.

Answer (score 5):

Consider $x=g+g^{-1}$ and $y=g^2+g^{-2}$: note that
$$
xy=g^3+g^{-1}+g+g^{-3}=g^{-2}+g^{-1}+g+g^2=x+y
$$
Thus
$$
(1-x)(1-y)=1-x-y+xy=1
$$

Comment: What motivates this solution?

Comment: @lhf I first tried to compute the powers of $x=g+g^{-1}$, using the formal $(1-x)^{-1}=1+x+x^2+\dotsb$; since $x^2=g^2+2+g^{-2}$ it was quite natural to set $y=g^2+g^{-2}$ and then to find out $xy=x+y$.

Answer (score 3):

We have $x=1-g-g^4$. The extended Euclidean algorithm for $\gcd(1-g-g^4,g^5-1)$ [gives](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=polynomialextendedgcd%5B1-g-g%5E4,g%5E5-1,g%5D)
$$
1 = (1 - g^2 - g^3)(1-g-g^4)+(-g - g^2)(g^5-1)
$$
Therefore, the inverse of $x$ is $1 - g^2 - g^3$ because $g^5-1=0$.

Comment: This is useful. But I do want to remind the OP that running Euclid here more typically takes us outside of the ring of polynomials with integer coefficients.